# What is the default folder for classes extending java.io.Reader and why?

Tags: java, standards

What is the default folder that classes that extend java.io.Reader take input from? For instance, where is "data.txt" supposed to be located in a call to FileReader such as the following?

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader("data.txt");
```

In the case of a project I'm currently working on (where I'm using Eclipse and its standard project directory structure), it seems to be the bin-folder. But where's the logic, isn't that folder supposed to contain .class-files and similar don't-touch compiler output?

What is standard practice here, is it really to put folders containing input data under bin/?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file is looked for in the current working directory, the one you are in when you start your application.

Comment: Eclipse starts it for me, so guess I have to read up on exactly how it does that.

Comment: Default current working directory is your bin folder when starting it from an IDE, unless you mess with with parameters akin to startup folder. Thing to think about is do you want the ability for the code to read that file from a diferent place but the one you deploy. If you don't, what you should do is get the path of your application and work from that, not rely on current working folder.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson When I start my applications from my IDE the current working directory is the project directory, not the bin directory.

Comment: But that would mean data.txt would have to in your project directory, and you said it was in bin. Which I presume is a subfolder off teh project direectory

Comment: @Tony That is exactly what it means. I haven't said anything was in 'bin'.

Comment: @EJP. oops, confused you with OP. Looks like your set up is different to their's though.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson My setup is Netbeans, the OP's is Eclipse. You can't make one rule for all IDEs.

Comment: @EJP. Why did you post where your current working directory is, given you know you are using a different IDE? I couldn't know that could I? Given you did post t and you did know they were different environments, makes me wonder what your problem is.